# Creating two custom buttons

Tags: android, button, custom-component

Can some one please help me on creating custom buttons like below? Is it possible? Have searched a lot and was able to find only some things which again turn out to be `rectangular/square shapes`. But I want two buttons to be `triangular` and to be arranged on up on the other and clickable only on their particular occupied areas. Code snippets are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Its possible in logical way by creating an image that look like the above picture. Because you can't re-shape the command buttons.

Comment: @Raynold But if we create an image, the how can the click events be separated on their respective shapes?

Comment: how do you do for solve this problem? I have this question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797430/android-complex-shape-button

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by extending `View` and subclassing its [`onTouchEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method, like this

```
public class BottomLeftTriangleButton extends View {

    // Copy superclass contructors

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getX() / getWidth() < event.getY() / getHeight()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This way, your custom view only intercept clicks on the bottom left area, corresponding to your "button 2" area. You can make the other area clickable by changing the "<" sign to ">".

Then put your 2 views in the same `FrameLayout`, and you're done.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to create triangular buttons and arrange up on one another like in the image above?

Comment: Put your 2 custom buttons in the same `FrameLayout`, and set `android:background` for both of them to your button images. There is no default resource for triangle buttons, you'll have to do the images yourself. You can use a [State List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to use different images for pressed and normal states.

Comment: Thanks for your time. My question is how to prepare those kind of custom buttons.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "prepare"? [Add your custom views in your XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) and you're good to go.